# Why does PHP give undefined index yet still return data for that index?

Tags: php

I have this in a logging function

```
$e = new Exception ();

$stack = $e -> getTrace ();
$exclude = 'foo.php';

while (isset ($stack [0])
  && ($exclude === substr ($stack [0] ['file'], -strlen($exclude))
      || 'error_handler' === $stack [0] ['function']))
{
    array_shift ($stack);
}
```

Sometimes this gives

```
Undefined index: file in bar.php on line 84
```

What's weird is that if I print out the contents of `$stack[0]` at any point then there is a `file` index within that array.

I can avoid this error by adding

```
isset ($stack [0] ['file'])
```

in the while condition, but it is logically redundant -- `file` is *always* present in `$stack[0]`, I have verified this manually. Furthermore, if I print `$stack[0]['file']` within the loop (after the `shift`) then it can emit an `Undefined index` warning and *still print the data for that index*.

How can this be happening?

Comment: It would help if your question included mock data to initialize `$stack`.

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve]

Comment: @arkascha White space between brackets is [perfectly acceptable](https://3v4l.org/S510W).

Comment: ^ It just looks so odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `'file'` is **not** always present:

```
function foo() {
  var_dump((new \Exception)->getTrace()[0]);
}
call_user_func('foo', []);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["function"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["args"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    &array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

There is an [ancient bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44428) report on this, but it will not be fixed. If you're using `'file'`, then guard for `'file'`, because if the trace flows through a `call_user_func` (or friends) you won't have it.